# How to get Acknowledgement after message send to destination in mirth

Tags: hl7, mirth

I created one channel, receiving inbound messages using LLP Listener connector type. I am using Send Ack radio button. We know that Once channel received the message by default it will send the acknowledgement to the sender. I could see the response from mapping tab of the view messages option. But i want to get the Ack that was sent to Sender by progrmatically. How can i code, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the forum links below this is not possible in ver 2 of Mirth:

[Where is the ACK message history/log?](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=7845)

[How to check the HL7 Ack message that Mirth sends back to the originating system?](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=8747)

Of the options mentioned in those post I would opt to create my own custom ACK response (which mirrors the default Mirth ack) and then you'll have access to it.